# Overlay a raster image using Equirectangular projection (lat/lon) onto OSM/Google map with openlayers?

Tags: openstreetmap, openlayers, mercator

I have a forecast map of 6x6 lat/lon extend from 104E-110E, 10N-16N as an static PNG image and want to make it an overlay on the basemap of OSM/Google map using openlayers 3. The problem is OSM uses Mercator project while my images uses Equirectangular and the maps don't fit.

You can see my implementation at
http://thoitiet.hus.vnu.edu.vn/?m=meteo&a=ol

Maybe there are methods where I can transform the image to Mercator first, but it's much better if openlayers can handle the correct projection. How/Is it possible that can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently image reprojection on the fly is not icluded in OL library, your best shot is to reproject your image with gdal then use a `ol.source.StaticImage` for displaying it on the map.

The raster reprojection is a work in progress, you can have a look to these links to have more information about that:

[OL 3 Google group discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=de#!searchin/ol3-dev/reproject/ol3-dev/KjBbhq4USm8/qRT2Ny9jXBIJ)

[OL3 Github issue](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/3785)

[Specifications](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Vs3DTRjpgf53sqbBCfauGaPZa1iFX7Br8yDlEG_W6CI/edit?pli=1)

[Examples](http://www.bdcc.co.uk/ol3/examples/)